# Double For Each Loop in VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I work on Excel, with 2 sheets called "Releves" and "Observations". I want to color a column of the Releves sheets based on the content of the cells of a column of the Observations Sheets.

The statement would be this one :

> if cells of *my_column_observations_sheet* are not empty, put a yellow
>   color in *my_column_releves_sheet*.

I made a double for each loop but it does not work. When I run the script, all the cells of *the my_column_releves_sheet* are colored, even if the cells of *my_column_observations_sheet* are empty...

Here is my script :

```
Sub condition()

Dim espece As Range
Dim num_releve As Range

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Relevé").Activate
Set num_releve = ActiveSheet.Range("G3:G6")

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Observations").Activate
Set espece = ActiveSheet.Range("B3:B6")

    For Each i In espece
        For Each j In num_releve
        If Not IsNull(i.Value) Then j.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: That's because `IsNull(any cell value)` is always going to be `False` no matter what's in that cell. Did you mean to check for `IsEmpty`?

Answer (score 1):

```
For Each i In espece
    For Each j In num_releve
        If Not IsNull(i.Value) Then j.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    Next
Next
```

`IsNull` can't be used like this. An empty cell value is *empty*, not *null*. Use `IsEmpty` instead:

```
For Each i In espece
    For Each j In num_releve
        If Not IsEmpty(i.Value) Then j.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    Next
Next
```

That will treat a cell that has a formula that returns an empty string, as a non-empty cell.

If you need to treat empty-valued cells as *empty*, then check for an empty string - but beware of error values:

```
For Each i In espece
    For Each j In num_releve
        If Not IsError(i.Value) Then
            If CStr(i.Value) <> vbNullString Then j.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Thank you ! But I have the same result.. All my j cells are colored even if the associated cells i are empty.. Maybe there'is a problem in the double for each loop ?

Comment: You haven't clarified what you're trying to do with `IsNull`. Problem isn't the loops, it's the condition inside it.